# Cannot update profile permission b/c it requires updating another permission

Tags: permissions, security, custom-profile, user-profile

Has anyone worked around this?
I have a custom profile. When I make ANY update to the profile, it tells me another permission is dependent on Read access on Opportunities.

I go to enable Read on Opportunities... but then yet another permission requires READ access on Accounts, for example.

And when I try to add Read access to Accounts, it gives me the error on Opportunities...
Has anyone else encountered and gotten past this catch-22? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Enhanced Profile Editor can sometimes act a bit weird; if you continue having problems, consider turning it off. You'll find it in Setup > User Interface, and unchecking "Enable Enhanced Profile User Interface." The older interface automatically checks all of the required dependencies for you.

Comment: Worked! Thanks. I will probably keep it off. It doesn't help much anywhere.